# Set primary key with mixture of two other properties in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, primary-key

As Realm does not support multiple columns as a primary key, I want to set primary key with mixture of two other properties in Realm. Here is the my object

```
@interface SampleRealmObject : RLMObject
@property (nullable) NSString *myPrimaryKey;
@property (nullable) NSString *myProperty1;
@property (nullable) NSString *myProperty2;
@end

@implementation SampleRealmObject
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    // return combination of myProperty1 and myProperty2
}
@end
```

Comment: Just use `myPrimaryKey ` as primarykey, and product `myPrimaryKey` value from `myProperty1 ` and `myProperty2` when you create the object?

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks, good choice, I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Primary key should be precomputed. And you shouldn't change it. Probably you should compute primary key during object construction and set into myPrimaryKey property.

Comment: @EvgenBodunov yes, I'm not sure but I guess if there is any method to manipulate object before storing to Realm can be helpful in this case.

Comment: There's no better way, no database allow non-property value to be primary key

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard there are no any builtin callbacks for that, but you can always set it before adding the object to the database.